# Java Socket get unusable after exception

Tags: java, sockets, networking, winsock

**Problem**

In a desktop network application upon sending data to DatagramSocket sometimes the exceptiption occur:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): Datagram send failed
```

After this exception socket is completely unusable: it doesn't recieve anything and send() hangs indefinitely. The reproducing test is a trivial app (create socket, bind, while (true) send();)

I can repeat this behavior in 100% of cases only on Windows when my machine goes to sleep mode and then come back in a middle of "intensive data flow".

**The questions are**:

1. is this behavior normal for bsd sockets - to get unusable after an error? or it is a kind of WSA bug?
2. is there any way to "reset" faulty socket to working state or reopening socket is the only solution?
3. is it possible to distinguish such conditions from regular I/O errors (i.e. recoverable ones) after catching exception?
4. are there any general guidance/advices on when I shall reopen sockets in application (I mean: network address changed, PC sleep/wake-up and other events)

Thanks! :)

Comment: I've repeated this tests now, in september, and... heh.. exception still occurs but it doesn't render socket unusable anymore. I.e. it can be ignored and communication on socket may proceed. I've spotted several big updates in my Win7 during this time, so probably MS guys have fixed something in WSA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket is unusable after any exception at all with the exception of SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: there is also PortUnreachableException, I can't check right now, but think it will be thrown for UDP sockets too, docs say: `Signals that an ICMP Port Unreachable message has been received on a connected datagram.` However I don't know what 'connected datagram' is ('socket' word is missing?)...

Comment: @tuxSlayer correct, thank you. After a PortUnreachableException it would be wise to desist sending to that address, and you could disconnect the socket and use it for sending to other addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be safe to assume that the socket is no longer usable, if reading from or writing to the socket causes an exception to be thrown. What kind of recoverable I/O errors would you expect in such a situation?

Comment: I guess some kind of "Port Unreachable" ICMP message while sending UDP datagrams may trigger an excetion... no? :)

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect that. If you send an UDP datagram, there is neither an acknowledge if the packet is received nor an error report if the receiver address is unreachable.

Comment: Yeah, I know than udp is unreliable, but from some hosts/networks I getting this errors though. BSD socket API for native code even define error codes for such cases (host unreachable, network unreachable)... Moreover, the error condition may be detected on a local host (no route to host for instance) and thus may be reported. To be honest I don't remember such errors from java sockets, but in a native code its ok to ignore such errors or handle them as recoverable.